# how many times number appeared in number (Number-ception) C

Tags: c, string, recursion

I need help with a problem in C. So i'm basically trying to find out how can i see how many times a number is in a number , for example :

```
16 in 5167163 = 2
33 in 34333 = 1
```

But the thing is that the number should not overlap , like 33 in 333 is only 1 time.I need an idea how to do this .

Code so far :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i,j;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n][2];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting -- why did you add the tag "string"? Was that supplied as a hint?

Comment: please show us what you have made so far

Comment: Use `while`, `strlen()` and `strpos()`.

Comment: The thing is , i don't know whether I should make it as string or leave it as it is(thought maybe there is some kind of mathematical formula to check)

Comment: Okay, I'm not going to write it out but here is a hint: `%` (when using numbers). It's also possible with strings, but I think a numerical solution is easier in this case.

Comment: Okey for numbers but how to make it not overlap like for example
`788 in 78877887  : 2` , I can't think of any mathematical solution for this with `%(mod)`

Comment: Convert numbers to strings(`sprintf()`), look for patterns (`strstr()`), advance if pattern found.

Comment: @chux Will this work even if numbers overlap `33 in 34333 : 1` like this ?

Comment: Yes, advance by the location of the found pattern + the width of the pattern before looking for the next pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t count(  int x, int y )
{
    const unsigned int BASE = 10;
    unsigned int a = abs( x );
    size_t n = 0;


    do
    {
        unsigned int z = a;
        unsigned int b = abs( y );
        _Bool equal = 0;

        do
        {
            equal = a % BASE == b % BASE;
            a /= BASE;
            b /= BASE;
        } while ( equal && a != 0 && b != 0 );

        if ( b == 0 && equal )
        {
            ++n;    
        }
        else
        {
            a = z / BASE;
        }
    } while ( a );

    return n;
}

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "count( 5167163, 16 ) = %zu\n", count( 5167163, 16 ) );
    printf( "count( 34333, 33 ) = %zu\n", count( 34333, 33) );
    printf( "count( 1000, 0 ) = %zu\n", count( 1000, 0) );
    printf( "count( 12323, 123 ) = %zu\n", count( 12323, 123 ) );
    printf( "count( 33333, 33 ) = %zu\n", count( 33333, 33 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
count( 5167163, 16 ) = 2
count( 34333, 33 ) = 1
count( 1000, 0 ) = 3
count( 12323, 123 ) = 1
count( 33333, 33 ) = 2
```

If your compiler does not support type `_Bool` you may use type `int` instead.

```
int equal = 0;
```

Comment: @dariomtc If the answer solved your problem then mark the answer as helpful that to close the question.:)

Answer (score 1):

This is pure numeric solution. It's not written in C but it's walkthrough how to do it. I think that it's pretty obvious what's going on in here.
I made it quickly in ruby console. You can clearly see an algorithm there.
Good luck

```
2.1.4 :001 > a = 5167163
 => 5167163
2.1.4 :002 > b = 16
 => 16
2.1.4 :003 > c = 10
 => 10
2.1.4 :004 > found = 0
 => 0
2.1.4 :005 > (a - b) % c
 => 7
2.1.4 :006 > a = a / (c**1)
 => 516716
2.1.4 :007 > (a - b) % c
 => 0
2.1.4 :008 > found += 1
 => 1
2.1.4 :009 > a = a / (c**2) # we have to power the radix to number of digits in b (use log(b, 10) for that
 => 5167
2.1.4 :010 > (a - b) % c
 => 1
2.1.4 :011 > a = a / (c**1)
 => 516
2.1.4 :012 > (a - b) % c
 => 0
2.1.4 :013 > found += 1
 => 2
2.1.4 :014 > a = a / (c**2) # we have to power the radix to number of digits in b (use log(b, 10) for that
 => 5
2.1.4 :015 > (a - b) % c
 => 9
2.1.4 :016 > a = a / (c**1)
 => 0
2.1.4 :017 >
```

If you want to get the number of digits of a number in given radix, you can use math log in given radix (flooring the result).

Enjoy